# IIS does not see the virtual disks on the local system

Tags: asp.net, iis, driveinfo

The system has a virtual disk connected to another server (M:) There is an application on IIS that requires access to files on this virtual disk.

```
DriveInfo[] dis = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

Returns the disks A, C, D, F - ie Local drives and discs.

In the console application, it works fine

```
DriveInfo[] dis = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

Returns A, C, D, F, M

In IIS server, pools and site work with the user with admin permissions

Comment: The virtual disk is connected by the User, the IIS runs as service and not interact with the UI. Its logical that you can not see it, Its like two different users - the one have the virtual disk, the other is not.

Comment: hi @aristos. IIS (server, pool and site) works under **same** user who connect virtual disk

Comment: The IIS and Pool is run as service, the connection you talk about is done from file explorer of windows that have access to the UI, serviced did not have that. Try to direct connect and not use virtual disk. Virtual disk is done from the user interface.